# Is it possible to get entity with navigation properties from DbContext without knowing primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using EF 6.1 I want to be able to return a single entity from the DbContext, with its navigation properties populated, without knowing the primary key.

So for example the entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int SomeSortOfPrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public virtual SomeOtherEntity SomeOtherEntity { get; set; }
}
```

I have an instance of the entity available so I have tried:

```
var entityWithNavProps = _dbContext.Entry(entity).Entity;
```

But this doesn't get the entity with it's navigation properties. Obviously the `.Find()` method doesn't work either as it's expecting a string, guid or integer.

Is there any other way to use an entity, and the DbContext to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The error when I did `.Find(entity)`:

_Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported_

Comment: Where did the instance of your entity come from?

Comment: It's either "manually created" if you like, or more usually from `DbContext.Entry()`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

You need to supply the reference navigation property's id.

For example, given these models.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't provide reference id or you provide invalid id, it will not load the reference.

```
// AuthorId = 0 is invalid id.
var book = new Book { Id = 1, AuthorId = 0 };
db.Books.Attach(book);
db.Entry(book).Reference(b => b.Author).Load();
```

[image: Result]

When you provide the valid reference id, it will load the reference.

```
// AuthorId = 1 is a valid id.
var book = new Book { Id = 1, AuthorId = 1 };
db.Books.Attach(book);
db.Entry(book).Reference(b => b.Author).Load();
```

[image: Result]

PS: Unless it's a **collection** navigation property.